# Unique ID Generation From DB value with 11 digits using Java causing Unique constraint exception

Tags: java, oracle, unique-constraint, unique-key

I have a requirement where we need to generate unqiue block ID which will be 11 characters.

We have below logic to generate it,

```
public String generateBlockId(){
        boolean alreadyExists = true;
        String newBlockId = "";
        
        while(alreadyExists) {
        
            newBlockId = generateYYDDDSSSSSString();
            
            Allocation allocation = repo.findTopByBlockId(newBlockId);
            if(allocation == null) {
                blockIdAlreadyExists = false;
            }
        }
        
        return newBlockId;
    }
    
    
public String generateYYDDDSSSSSString() {
        String dateString;
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        Integer year = now.getYear() % 100;
        Integer day = now.getDayOfYear();
        Integer second = now.toLocalTime().toSecondOfDay();
        String YY = StringUtils.leftPad(year.toString(), 2, "0");
        String DDD = StringUtils.leftPad(day.toString(), 3, "0");
        String SSSSSS = StringUtils.leftPad(second.toString(), 6, "0");
        dateString = YY + DDD + SSSSSS;
        return dateString;
    }
```

We have utmost 100 concurrent users at time and it is having performance impact and causing unique constraint exception when generated id is stored to the DB.

Is there any better solution to this issue.

**Note :** The business requirement is to have 11 digits only.

Comment: Well, a timestamp is rarely unique so there is a chance 2 users generate the id in the same second. Why don't you use a simple sequence generator, either in code or in your DB to handle this?

Comment: @Thomas . This is only 11 characters, so there is a chance in future it may run out of sequence!

Comment: Sure, but no matter how you're generating those numbers you'll eventually run out of sequence. An 11-digit number allows for up to 1 trillion unique ids so if you're afraid your application will use more then using a second-precision timestamp will be even riskier.

Answer (score 0):

First things first - maybe you should get back to business and verify why they need 11 digits constraint ;)

Anyway if particular user can make only one request at a time (i.e. no concurrent request from single user) I would include user id (or some part of it) in generated id. In such case generated ids should not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I think I probably did not get the question but I will do my best.

perhaps a better way would be to use UUIDs? is using timestamp a requirement?

I added an example below

```
    public static String generateId() {
    //Create new uuid
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    //Convert the uuid to string and strip it from "-"
    String id = uuid.toString().replace("-", "");
    //Trim the UUID and retrieve the chars until the 11th char.
    id = id.substring(0, 11);
    //Return the id back
    return id;
}
```